# Will Android studio HAXM support for this PC specification?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, intel, haxm

This is my pc specification. Will Android studio HAXM work on this pc?

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 8.1
Version 6.3.9600 Build 9600
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name MAX-PC
System Manufacturer LENOVO
System Model    INVALID
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  Montevina_Fab
Processor   Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU       T4500  @ 2.30GHz, 2300 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   LENOVO 4FCNA1WW, 12/26/2011
SMBIOS Version  2.4
Embedded Controller Version 3.06
BIOS Mode   Legacy
BaseBoard Manufacturer  LENOVO
BaseBoard Model Not Available
BaseBoard Name  Base Board
Platform Role   Mobile
Secure Boot State   Unsupported
PCR7 Configuration  Binding Not Possible
Windows Directory   C:\Windows
System Directory    C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Locale  United States
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "6.3.9600.16384"
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 2.00 GB
Total Physical Memory   1.93 GB
Available Physical Memory   261 MB
Total Virtual Memory    3.59 GB
Available Virtual Memory    447 MB
Page File Space 1.66 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions    No
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions   No
Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware    No
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection Yes
```

I get this error when trying to start emulator in android studio:

**C:\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_19 -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!**

If I can't install HAXM, how do I run emulator without haxm in android studio?

Answer (score 1):

**HAXM Installation**

Intel HAXM requires the Android* SDK to be installed (version 17 or higher). For more information, refer to the Android* developer website (http://developer.android.com/sdk/).

Hardware Requirements:

Intel® processor with support for **Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality
At least 1 GB of available RAM**
Supported Operating Systems:

Microsoft Windows® 10 (32/64-bit)

Microsoft Windows* 8 and 8.1 (32/64-bit)

Microsoft Windows* 7 (32/64-bit)

Microsoft Windows Vista* (32/64-bit)

**Important:** Intel HAXM can be used only with Android* x86 emulator images provided by Intel. 
Intel HAXM cannot be used with ARM* Android* emulator images or non-Intel x86 Android* emulator images.

Downloading Intel® HAXM
ates automatically. To get the latest version, download the Intel HAXM package using the Android* SDK Manager (recommended) or from the Intel® Developer Zone Android* developer site.

Downloading Manually

Go to http://software.intel.com/en-us/android.

-Choose the Intel HAXM installer package for your platform.

-Extract the installer and follow installation instructions for your platform.

OR

-Downloading through Android* SDK Manager(Reccomended).

-Start the Android* SDK Manager

-Under Extras, check the box next to "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM).

-The SDK Manager will download the installer to the "extras" directory, under the main SDK directory.

- Even though the SDK manager says "Installed" it actually means that the Intel HAXM executable was downloaded.
  You will still need to run the installer from the "extras" directory to get it installed.

-Run the installer inside the /sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/directory and follow the installation instructions for your platform.

Ref: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Answer (score 0):

The T4500 does not support virtualization. You'll need to go with ARM emulation instead of x86.